# Where does `QFSFileEngine::open: No file name specified` come from?

Tags: c++, qt, macros, qt5, warnings

I'm taking a look in a Qt project codebase, it's big enought I can't find from where the following is comming from.

```
QFSFileEngine::open: No file name specified
```

So far I tried two approaches:

1. I tried to put a breakpoint near every `QFile::open()` but that didn't led me any closer do find the issue.
   I step over all breakpoints with a clean output and then somewhere after I get a couple of:

```
QFSFileEngine::open: No file name specified
QFSFileEngine::open: No file name specified
QFSFileEngine::open: No file name specified
QFSFileEngine::open: No file name specified
```

2. Used a macro to replace an instance of `QFile` by `MyFile` (did it before anything else in `main.cpp`):

```
    class MyFile : public QFile
    {
        int i = 0;
    
    public:
        MyFile(const QString &name, QObject *parent)
        {
            qDebug() << "a";
        }
    
        MyFile(QObject *parent)
        {
            qDebug() << "b";
        }
    
        MyFile()
        {
            qDebug() << "b";
        }
    
        MyFile(const QString& filename)
        {
            qDebug() << "d" << filename.size() << filename;
        }
    
        bool open(QIODevice::OpenMode flags)
        {
            qDebug() << i++ << flags;
    
            return true;
        }
    
    };
    
    #define QFile MyFile
```

With this I was expecting to break code logic as a side effect, but a least stop the:

```
QFSFileEngine::open: No file name specified
```

However I still get them.

Can I conclude the `QFSFileEngine::open: No file name specified` are not comming from my project but
from a 3rd party library loaded by my project?

Any suggestiongs on another approches I should try?

Comment: Try installing a message handler using [`qInstallMessageHandler`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#qInstallMessageHandler).  Then run under a debugger with a breakpoint in your handler when the message of interest is received.  The backtrace should point you at the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

If the user selects no filename by pressing Cancel in the dialog, `QFileDialog` returns the following message: `"No file selected"`. This means that the user did not provide any input and the program cannot proceed with the operation.

> Source: [Qt Documentation - QFileDialog](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qfiledialog.html)